# Meteor method + check() + audit-argument-checks + async/await causes exception

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I’m using meteor with check() and audit-check-arguments package.

When I use a meteor method using async/await and pass a parameter, even though I use check() to validate the function parametrs, the audit package still throws an exception indicating that not all input parameters have been checked. If I remove the async/await implementation, the package does not crib. What am I missing?

Example:

```
Meteor.methods({

    test: async function(param1){
          check(param1, String);
          ...
          await ....
    }
});
```

Throws an exception:

```
=> Client modified -- refreshing
I20200513-10:43:27.978(5.5)? Exception while invoking method 'test' Error: Did not check() all arguments during call to 'test'
I20200513-10:43:27.979(5.5)?     at ArgumentChecker.throwUnlessAllArgumentsHaveBeenChecked (packages/check/match.js:515:13)
```

Whereas this traditional meteor method does not throw any exceptions

```
Meteor.methods({

    test:  function(param1){
          check(param1, String);
          ...

    }
});
```

I know for sure that I am passing exactly one parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `audit-argument-checks` only works for synchronous functions.

I don't have this issue because we use [`mdg:validated-method`](https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#validated-method), which uses requires you to specify an argument validator for each method.

It shuts up the argument checker by wrapping the method function with this:

```
    // Silence audit-argument-checks since arguments are always checked when using this package
    check(args, Match.Any);
```

The simplest solution I can think of, is to separate the check from the async function. You could use a wrapper function to do this:

```
function checkAndRun(check, run) {
  return function(...args) {
    check.apply(this, args);
    return run.apply(this, args);
  }
}

Meteor.methods({
  'example': checkAndRun(
    function(exampleID){
      check(exampleID, String);
    },
    async function(exampleID) {
      const result = await doSomethingAsync(exampleID);
      SomeDB.update({ _id: exampleID }, { $set: { someKey: result.value } });
      return result.status;
    }
  }
});
```

or you could even do it inline with an async IIFE:

```
Meteor.methods({
  example(exampleID) {
    check(exampleID, String);
    return (async () => {
      const result = await doSomethingAsync(exampleID);
      SomeDB.update({ _id: exampleID }, { $set: { someKey: result.value } });
      return result.status;
    })()
  }
});
```

Which, come to think of it, is much simpler than the simplest solution I could think of at first

You just want to separate the sync check from the async method body somehow

---

In case you're curious, let diving through the source to see where it's called. When the method is called (in `ddp-server/livedata-server`), we end up here, a  sync method call for the first reference of `audit-argument-checks`: 
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js#L1767-L1770

Which takes us into `check/Match` for another sync call here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/71f67d9dbac34aba34ceef733b2b51c2bd44b665/packages/check/match.js#L114-L123

Which uses the strange `Meteor.EnvironmentVariable` construct, which under the hood has another sync call: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js#L57

Comment: Thanks! It just didn't occour to me to have the async function separately inside the meteor method. This should work for me